# Creating new folders on a Windows Phone device

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to create a directory (folder) on my phone. It shouldn't matter whether it is the phone's internal memory or a memory card. My current code is:

```
public void CreateDirectory(string directoryName)
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && !myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
            MessageBox.Show("Made");
        }
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("Exist");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

When I use Visual Studio to run my application directly on my phone, no directories are created.  I have tested the following inputs, but none appear to work:

```
CreateDirectory("DL");
CreateDirectory("\\DL");
CreateDirectory("/DL");
```

How can I create a directory on the phone?

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: i mean didn't create. i was search into my phone but DL folder not found but in my application said "Exist"

Comment: IsolatedStorage is not browsable/visible from other applications (hence the word "isolated") so if you're using a file browser app you will not be able to see it.